# Adding python folder to system variables isnt working

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have python 3.5 on my computer installed in

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35
```

I add this path to the variable `PATH` then i try python in command line then I am getting this error

```
"python" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or bath file
```

I even tried creating a new variable `PYTHONPATH` as suggested by one of the answers on stackoverflow but that didn't work for me

**Edit 1:** Yes , I can see the path when I enter the command `path` in the `cmd` . And yes the path is correct

path shown as in `cmd.exe` :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>path
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity
Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64
;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Win
dowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin
; C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35 ; C:\Users\admin\AppData
\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\atom\bin ;
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35 ; C:\Users\admin\AppData\L
ocal\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts

C:\Users\admin>
```

Comment: After adding your Python directory to the `PATH` variable, did you open a new command shell or re-use an existing one that was already open ? If you re-used an existing one, that is because Windows does not automagically refresh environment variable changes made (unless you alter them in that shell session of course.)

Comment: What command are you using to add that path to the `PATH` variable?

Comment: @ChristianWitts I closed the one that was opened and opened a new one

Comment: @zondo none .. `computer > properties > Advanced system settings > Environment variables > ***"Editted the PATH variable"***`

Comment: which path variable you edited?

Comment: In cmd check `path`. If the above installed path is not listed, then the path variable is not added properly.

Comment: @WhoAmI  I separated the path variables by semicolon .... Is that the mistake?

Comment: @SamratDas `Path` itself is the name of the variable

Comment: Did the installation path showed while you type `path` in CMD?

Comment: Can you run `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe`? What is the exact content of `PATH`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes I can run it and it is there in path variable along with some system path

Comment: That doesn't answer the question what the exact content of `PATH` is. Add that info to your question.

Comment: If cmd.exe cannot find python.exe by searching `PATH`, there is something wrong with the change that you made. It's probably something simple, but there's no point in guessing. Please edit your answer to include the exact value of `PATH` from the `path` command (i.e. copy and paste; do not type it in).

Comment: @ChristianWitts, there is some automagic involved. Explorer automatically refreshes its environment variables in response to a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message, which gets broadcasted to all top-level windows. However, cmd.exe is a console program that only has standard handles for a console window that's owned by conhost.exe. Since cmd isn't a GUI program that owns a top-level window, it can't participate in the automagic process. So you have to start a new command prompt that inherits an updated environment from Explorer.

Comment: @eryksun I've added it have a look

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've added it have a look

Comment: There shouldn't be spaces between entries in `PATH`. Also you only need to add the directory to either the system or user value of `PATH`. The user value gets concatenated to the end of the system value. Since your Python is installed for the current user only, it would make sense to add it to the user `PATH` variable, since other users won't have access to your user directory.

Comment: @eryksun that worked .. Silly space ... If you'd add that as answer then it would be great for future reference to other people

Answer (score 1):

Please check the path you are entering, is python exactly present on the same path you provided. For me I just tried to latest version of python on my windows 10 laptop, new installed path is `C:\Users\samra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32`, It was not on `---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35`
Check it and update your Path Variable, reopen the command prompt it should work.

Comment: the path is correct and it is displayed in the cmd too when i use the command `path` but still `python` gives the same error ..... Indeed strange `:/`!

Comment: you added to System Variable not to User Variable?

Comment: and also python executable file is present in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35

Comment: Hmm ... Initially I added to user variable .. Now I added to environmental variable ... But to no avail :(

Comment: can you copy the full Path, you had provided there?